# Return true/false on property value in PowerShell, not the value

Tags: powershell, boolean

I'm using PowerShell's `Get-ADuser` to pull some curated attributes (more than basic but less the `select *`).

Nothing too special, basically user created time, last log-on (required expression for that one I think), and a few others. Most are just simple property attribute returns. However, I also want to check for the presence `UserSmmimeCert`.

By itself, it can be pulled, but the return is the value of the SMIME key, so it's hideously long. I don't need the key; I just want a return of true/false if the field is present or not. I have a way to do this if the ONLY field I want is the `UserSmimeCertificate` (below), but I want it along side the other values I am pulling.

```
Get-ADUser -Identity $user -Properties userSmimeCertificate | select -ExpandProperty userSmimeCertificate) -is [System.Array]
```

So yeah, that will work as a one off, but I'm pulling about 10 property attributes back.

As a workaround option, I would also be happy if there was instead some way to say "just return the first x digits of the `UserSmimeCertificate`".

Comment: -iRon - Your example returns false even though there definitely is a usersmimecertificate on my account.

Comment: -boxdog - even if I drop your first suggestion directly into a .ps1 (only modifying to set the user directly, not as a variable) I get

"Add-Member : Cannot add a member with the name "USCertPresent" because a member with that name already exists. To overwrite the member anyway, add the Force parameter to your command"

Comment: I do not have the specific `userSmimeCertificate` attribute but I guess it always returns an array even it is empty. try: `[Bool]@(userSmimeCertificate).Length` Or `[Bool]userSmimeCertificate.count` if it is a collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an expression property for this, for example.:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties userSmimeCertificate | Select-Object Name, sid, @{Name="userSmimeCertificate"; Expression = {$_.userSmimeCertificate -is [System.Array]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally clear what you're looking for, but I think you want to get the current values of some properties along with a 'flag' that tells you if the certificate is present or not. If so, one way to do this is to add a new property to the returned objects:

```
Get-ADUser -Identity $user -Properties userSmimeCertificate |
    ForEach-Object {
        Add-Member -InputObject $_ `
                   -MemberType NoteProperty `
                   -Name USCertPresent `
                   -Value ($_.userSmimeCertificate -is [System.Array]) `
                   -PassThru
    }
```

This way, you get everything you had before along with a new property, `USCertPresent`, that is true or false, depending on the presence of certificate data.

If you want something simpler, with only the properties you need, then you can create a whole new object with just those ones:

```
 Get-ADUser -Identity $user -Properties userSmimeCertificate |
    ForEach-Object {
        Add-Member -InputObject $_ `
                    -MemberType NoteProperty `
                    -Name USCertPresent `
                    -Value ($_.userSmimeCertificate -is [System.Array]) `
                    -PassThru
    } | Select-Object Property1, Property2, Property3, USCertPresent
```

Just replace `Property1`, etc, with the names of the actual properties you want.