# Microsoft Graph API - How to update userSMIMECertificate

Tags: azure, outlook, certificate, azure-ad-graph-api, smime

Is it possible to update userSMIMECertificate object for a user in Azure active directory using graph API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use the graph API to upload the user SMIME certificate to AAD/Office365. The only workable solution available is to upload the SMIME Certificate using the Set-Mailbox PowerShell commandlet and setting the arguments -UserSMimeCertificate

Answer (score 1):

You could not to use Microsoft Graph API to update userSMIMECertificate.

You could use PowerShell cmdlet `set-aduser`

For more information, please refer to these links:

[Set-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/set-aduser?view=win10-ps)

[Update Active Directory user fields with powershell scrip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50341045/powershell-return-true-false-on-property-value-not-the-value)

[Powershell return true/false on property value, not the value](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ce7ebcaf-a082-4e48-8fd4-1dc5d37b250e/update-active-directory-user-fields-with-powershell-script?forum=winserverpowershell)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But we require a programmatic way to update the UserSMIMECertificate using c# to Azure AD. Do you recommend any ?

Comment: You could refer to this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.data.directory.management.mailbox.usersmimecertificate(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: The article refers to on-premise exchange. But I have no issue with the on-premise. The requirement is the hosted exchange in active directory.