# PowerShell Exchange Online 365 List S/MIME Certificate Expiration Date

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, office365, exchange-server, smime

Is there a command to query the Exchange Online server to get a list of users and the expiration date of their S/MIME certificate?

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName myusername@example.com
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Mailbox -SortBy Name | select Name,UserSMimeCertificate,UserCertificate
```

This lists the usernames and their S/MIME certificate.
I need also the expiration date of their S/MIME certificate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment.***

```
Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName  admin@xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com
```

Check the below way :

```
 Get-Mailbox -SortBy Name | select Name,UserSMimeCertificate,UserCertificate,Issuer, NotAfter, Subject, FriendlyName | FL
```

Also check [boolean - Return true/false on property value in PowerShell, not the value - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50341045/return-true-false-on-property-value-in-powershell-not-the-value)

[image]

I donot have certifictaes for users and are empty.

or check like.

```
$certificateproperties=Get-Mailbox -SortBy Name | select Name,UserSMimeCertificate,UserCertificate | FL

Foreach($user in $certificateproperties.Name )
{

Write-Host  $user
Get-ExchangeCertificate -Thumbprint <usercertthumbprint> | Format-List
}
```

place $usercertificate.thumbprint for its -Thumbprint

Where format list gives properties like ***`NotAfter`*** which is the expiration of certificate according to [get-exchangecertificate description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-exchangecertificate?view=exchange-ps#description)